# Бежать и бегать

Tags: классификация

Оба глагола - бегать и бежать - несовершенного вида, непереходные, имеют один и тот же корень (бегаю - бегу, бегай - беги, бегайте - бегите, бегают - бегут), но грамматическую категорию спряжения имеют разную. В чем тут дело? Неужели то или иное спряжение глаголов (чистая грамматика) влияет на смысл или даже оттенки смыслов слов?

Конь бежит по кругу. Конь бегает по кругу. Суффиксы разные, смысл практически одинаковый. Хотелось бы прояснить сам научный подход к этой проблеме. Если слова бегающий и бегущий чем-то различаются по смыслу (??), то каким образом совершенно "бездушные"суффиксы могут передавать нам эти семантические тонкости. Пишут, что бегущий означает "двигающийся в одном направлении", а бегающий - это "туда-сюда снующий". Но что же тогда означает форма "бежащий" :
"Иосиф, **бежащий** от сих мест, встречается с Пентефрием..." (Фон Визин)

И потом, надо вспомнить, что "бежать" употреблялось классиками как переходный глагол : "бежит любви, бежит услады нежной..." Это романтический герой в одном направлении бегает или в разных?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Бежать" и "бегать" разошлись по смыслу. Слово "бежать" имеет либо оттенок "побега, избегания" (бежать от проблем, беженец, беги-спасайся и так далее), либо делает упор на интенсивность движения или процесс движения как такового.

Что из этого следует? Что слова близкородственные и сильно пересекаются по смыслу, но все же не абсолютно синонимичны. Потому вполне могут иметь грамматические отличия. Потому и имеют, наверное, чтобы видно было отличия между ними.

Answer (score 3):

> Хотелось бы прояснить сам научный подход к этой проблеме.

Хочется - сделай.

> Но что же тогда означает форма "бежащий"

Бе**ж**енец.

Comment: Вы догадались, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Бежать vs. бегать - глаголы движения. Глаголы движения в русском языке - особая группа, образующая систему, то есть ее элементы делятся на группы на основании противопоставлений.
Основное противопоставление - однонаправленное движение (= находиться в пути из точки А в точку Б) vs. разнонаправленное движение (туда-обратно, многократно, без цели, умение и т.д.), это разбивает все глаголы движения на две группы "ИДТИ/ХОДИТЬ":

---------**непереходные** -----------
идти-ходить
бежать-бегать
ехать-ездить
лететь-летать
плыть-плавать
лезть-лазать (лазить)
ползти-ползать
брести-бродить

--------**переходные**----------
нести-носить
везти-возить
вести-водить
гнать-гонять
катить-катать
тащить-таскать 
(есть еще с частицей -ся).

Ср.:
*Я иду в школу* (я сейчас нахожусь в пути из А (напр., из дома) в В (в школу) /
*Я хожу в школу* (я каждый день хожу в школу (и возвращаюсь домой)).

*Мама идёт в комнату* (её цель - комната, это точка В) /
*Мама ходит по комнате* (кругами, без цели, туда-сюда).

*Птица летит* (в определенном направлении, сейчас находится в полете) /
*Пингвины не летают, пингвины хорошо плавают* (умеют).

Answer (score 1):

Они в принципе имеют два немного разных смысловых значения. Бежать - это направление. Бегать - совершать действие. Попробую на примерах...

Бежать на остановку. Бежать за троллейбусом. Бежать гонку (в направлении финиша)

Я люблю бегать каждый день. Я пробегаю 5 км каждый день

Comment: Я бегу, но он бежит — хоть и рядом, хоть и нога в ногу. Смысл действия один и тот же.

Comment: "Бегу" и "бежит" — это личные формы одного и то же глагола "бежать".

Answer (score 0):

"Бежать" - совершать действие прямо сейчас.

"Бегать" - совершать дейстсвие регулярно.

Очевидно, что это один глагол, который изменяется во времени. 
И для такого изменения нет устоявшейся грамматической категории.

Comment: Кому очевидно - и на каком основании?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо всё дело в том. что в русском языке недостаточно временных форм, например: бегу - укороченное настоящее время; бегаю - продолжительное настоящее время.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, отличие не во времени, а в грамматической категории аспекта (она большей частью остаётся почему-то за рамками образовательной программы, но к ней относится в частности вид). Помимо совершенный-несовершенный есть ещё однократно-многократно. Ломоносов что-то по этой схеме пытался систематизировать...

Comment: Каким образом "аспект" сказывается на выборе парадигмы спряжения?!

Answer (score 0):

Скажу о ***спортивном*** аспекте слов *"бежать"* и *"бегать". "Бегать"* в спорте значит вообще *тренироваться* или *совершать конкретную тренировку,* а *"бежать"* означает *бежать гонку, забег, то есть выступать **в данный момент** в конкретном старте.* Но опять же можно сказать, к примеру: *Этот спортсмен регулярно / каждый год **бегает** Лондонский марафон,* делая акцент на регулярности, но: *Этот (тот же) спортсмен сейчас **бежит** очередной свой Лондонский марафон,* если он действительно его ***бежит*** в данный момент.

Answer (score -1):

Все банально, если понимаете название буквиц "Гаголь" и "Живот". В глаголе "БЕГАТЬ" есть слог "ГА" - обозначающий перемещение. А в глаголе "БЕЖАТЬ" слог "ЖА" - означает основу жизни. Так вот бегать без смысла и делает это "бегун" - человек выполняющий одну функцию перемещения, А вот "БЕЖЕНЕЦ" человек совершает свои действия исходя из жизненной необходимости.
Вспоминайте хотя бы названия буквиц.